# How to break on a XMLHttpRequest event and edit the call's arguments before running the request to completion

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Using Google Chrome, I would like to break before a specified XMLHttpRequest event is fired in order to manipulate its arguments data.

So far, I managed to to break on an XHR call event, but I couldn't figure out how to manipulate the call's input before it is fired and sent to the server - **my main goal is to manipulate/change the argument of the request**.

Here is a snapshot of my current work using the Chrome DevTools:
[image]

Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried the **XHR Breakpoints** feature on the **Sources** panel? I'm pretty sure that'll break before the request is sent out. From there you can inspect and manipulate the data from the **Console**.

[image: XHR breakpoints]

You can see the pane on the right of the screenshot above.

Another way to set breakpoints on XHRs is from the Event Listener Breakpoints pane. From here you can trigger breakpoints on various stages of the XHR lifecycle.

[image: XHR lifecycle breakpoints]

Take the following fiddle for example: https://jsfiddle.net/kaycebasques/jdf20gn4/1/

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = {"a": 1, "b": 2};
xhr.open('GET', 'https://httpbin.org/get');
xhr.send(params);
```

I created the "Any XHR" breakpoint by pressing the plus sign next to **XHR Breakpoints** and then just pressing `Enter`.

When the breakpoint is paused, you can see the currently defined variables in the **Scope** pane, above **XHR Breakpoints**.

[image: scope]

To modify XHR data, you just find the variable that you're looking for in the Scope pane, and then use the Console to modify that variable.

[image: modify xhr data]

Comment: I couldn't find a way to edit the request data before running to completion

Comment: @YairNevet I updated my answer to include an example. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks mate :) for some reason, although I managed to manipulated the parameter value, the request is still being sent with the old value to the server. I think that I need to break on a certain stage of the XHR flow, the question is on which stage

Comment: Hey @YairNevet check the answer again. I updated it to describe how you can set breakpoints on various stages of the XHR lifecycle.

Comment: I think setting the breakpoint on [readystate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) would do the trick...

Comment: @KayceBasques +1 for this. Here, you show editing parameters. Could the breakpoint be used to even edit the XHR request URI ?

Comment: @SiddhantRimal while the page is paused call `xhr.open('GET', 'https://example.com')` from the Console, where `xhr` is the reference to the XHR object, `GET` is the HTTP method name, and `https://example.com` is the other URL that you want to request instead.